# How does one correctly connect separate files (classes to functions etc)?

Tags: python

I have been working on a program and am self taught. I am now trying to officially organize my code so I can work with it easier and make it easier for anyone coming into the project. I think I'm not quite grasping the concept of things. I have many classes and functions that all interconnect to some degree. Upon running what I have, I get error below but I am importing the file and running through the **init** file, I think? Below is some of the code in question.

**Error:**
"NameError: name 'profile' is not defined"

**In main (IDScribe)**

```
import threading
import pygame
import random
import time
import math
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from init import *

active_profile = profile("Inch", 0, 0, 0)
```

**In "**init**":**

```
import threading
import pygame
import random
import time
import math
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

import init.classes
from init import classes
```

**In classes:**

```
import pygame
from IDScribe import *
class profile():
    def __init__(self, unit, shade, color_change, corner_marks):
        self.unit = unit
        self.shade = shade
        self.color_change = color_change
        self.corner_marks = corner_marks
```

Comment: Why is `init` importing itself? Shouldn't it be `from classes import profile`?

Comment: It's not, or at least it shouldn't be. When posting, it changed the ____init____ to just bolded init. There is an ____init____.py file inside of the init folder, as well as the classes file

Comment: `import init.classes
from classes import profile`

in init gives the same error